# Turning HTML content in to a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas

I have some stuff I want to add into a canvas element, I want to use HTML to create the data, because I am using a framework to get user data, and it can't put the data in an canvas object.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="load-this-to-canvas">
    
      <div style="background: rgb(55, 55, 55); width: 350px; height: 400px;">
        
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/160709493032878080/20b3333152f8b57ad0da549ffd0a6757.png?size=64" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; position: relative; top: 10px; left: 10px; float: left; border-radius: 64px;" />
        
        <div style="color: rgb(51, 153, 255); position: relative; top: 30px; left: 26px; float: left; font-size: 22px; font-family: sans-serif;">
          ✪ΔTMΘZFΞΔR✪
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <div style="margin-left: 10px; color: white; font-family: 'Helvetica'; font-size: 14px;">
          Full name: My Secret Name<br>
          Email: mysecretemail@theteamcoders.com<br>
          Age: 17<br>
          Birth: 06.03 (1999)<br>
          Status: <span style="color: rgb(255, 50, 50); font-weight: bold;">Administrator</span><br>
          Website: https://theteamcoders.com/Home<br>
          Banned: Never<br>
          Ban date: ()<br>
          Motto: "No programming, no life."<br>
          <br>
          Password salt: "Cookies taste good"<br>
          Startup directory: "/VM/vm1/drive/startup.snnly"
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would I make this html go into a canvas element?

> Note! No data will be displayed the same way as an HTML page, but the data will be loaded to JS

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: No no no @MikeMcCaughan, it is very possible to turn HTML elements into a canvas object, seen people done it before, but could not find it anywhere on the internet...

Comment: I didn't say if it's possible or not. Read *all* of the answers to that question and you'll find ways of doing it.